# Symfony SAAS multitenant (DB by tenant). Sharing my implementation

Tags: symfony, caching, authentication, multi-tenant, saas

*I people! First: sorry about my english (I'm improving it...). Thanks for edit de post to corret it :)*

I'm implementing a SaaS app multitenant on symfony. I wish share with the community what is the way that I've used (mae by not the best, but it works fine...).

**THE CONCEPT:**

- One code (one app).
- A DB for each tenant
- A CSS for each tenant
- Each client have a subdomain like (www.tenant1.myapp.com, www.tenant2.myapp.com)

**FIRST: ARRANGING THE CONFIGURATION**

I've arranged the configuration files in folders like this:

```
-app
---config
-----tenantA
--------config.yml
--------config_dev.yml
--------config_prod.yml
--------parameters.yml
-----tenantB
--------config.yml
--------config_dev.yml
--------config_prod.yml
--------parameters.yml
-----services.yml
-----security.yml
```

**DISPATCHER**

On AppKernel I've modiffied the registerContainerConfiguration action. It loads de general configuration (DB parameters, twig globals, etc....).

Original:

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
$loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

}
```

New (I used the subdomain to set what is the environment that symfony have to load:

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
        $url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $partes = explode('.',$url);
        $tenant= $partes[0]; // this get de subdomain. If the access is www.tenant1.myapp.com this returns tenant1.
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/'.$tenant.'/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

This function goes to the tenant folder and load the config file with his parameters.yml

**ARRANGING CACHE AND LOG FOLDERS**

I've modified the AppKernel including the functions getCacheDir and getLogDir in order to set the correct folder to save the files:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
   return $this->rootDir . '/cache/' . $tenant. '/' . $this->environment;
}

public function getLogDir()    
{     
    return $this->rootDir . '/logs/' . $tenant. '/' . $this->environment;   
}
```

This save the files like:

```
-cache
---tenant1
-----dev
-----prod
---tenant2
-----dev
-----prod

-logs
---tenant1
-----dev.log
-----prod.log
----tenant2
------dev.log
------prod.log
```

**CSS BY TENANT**

I've arranged my css files by tenant like this:

```
--web
---css
----tenant1.css
----tenant2.css
----tenantN.css
```

Then, in the config.yml of each tenant (remind the arranged folders on app->config) I used a global tiwg with the name of the css theme of the tenant:

```
twig:
    globals:
        app_css: tenant1.css
```

Then, in the tiwg where i've declared the css files and include in the base twig I call the css by:

```
{% set cssload = "css/" ~ app_css  ~ ".css" %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{cssload}}">
```

As the cache is saved in diferents folders, the CSS of tenant1 don't affects the cache and the css of tenant2.

Finish: I don't know if this is a good practice, but it works fine, and it's another solution.

Thanks everybody for the help of this days!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, i saw a lot of topics from you on the subjects, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks to the community for their help! :)

Comment: It’s really nice that you post a solution for your problem, but this is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. If you have previously posted questions about parts of the problem, you are more than welcome to self-answer them with your respective solution.

Comment: @lxg sorry. I'm new in this communtity.